# How to compress a large file?

Tags: python, compression, gzip

The problem I'm experiencing is the name of the stored file.  The stored file isn't named with the original/uncompressed file name. Instead the stored file is named with the archive name (with the appended ".gz" extension).

Expected Result:

```
file.txt.gz           {archive name}
....file.txt          {stored file name}
```

Actual Result:

```
file.txt.gz           {archive name}
....file.txt.gz       {stored file name}
```

Reading through the gzip documentation (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html) example code:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

How do I get the archive to store the file with the name "file.txt" instead of "file.txt.gz"?

Comment: So you want to store the compressed file in `file.txt`? i.e. overwrite the existing file?

Comment: I *believe* the OP is trying to put `file.txt` inside their `.gz` file, and they want the `file.txt` name to be the name of the file inside the `.gz` file, but they're getting a `file.txt.gz` file that contains a `file.txt.gz`.

Comment: But now that I'm looking around, don't think that gzip is an actual archive format, just a file compression -_-

Comment: You seem to be right there in a sense (it is a file format, but typically not for multiple entries, at least on its own), as "Compressed archives are typically created by assembling collections of files into a single tar archive, and then compressing that archive with gzip. The final .tar.gz or .tgz file is usually called a tarball." (Wikipedia)

Comment: However, after a little experimenting the filename is there in the gzip, expected to be in the gzip header, as renaming the archive does not affect the name of the file extracted from it. (Tried it outside python though.)

Comment: One more thought: I tried the code and it works fine, the file name is correctly stored in the archive ("file.txt").

Comment: @Jake it would be good to know more about which python version is actually being used and how you uncompress the file, as mine corresponds with the quoted documentation link, so if there's a problem that's not likely to be specific to 2.7 (but then we don't have many clues).

Comment: Yes, this is not how the `gzip` module _should_ work. Either you have found an old bug, there's a misunderstanding or there's something funny going on in your code.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `gzip.GzipFile()`; the shorthand `gzip.open()` won't do what you want.

Quoth [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile):

> When *fileobj* is not `None`, the *filename* argument is only used to be included in the **gzip** file header, which may include the original filename of the uncompressed file. It defaults to the filename of *fileobj*, if discernible; otherwise, it defaults to the empty string, and in this case the original filename is not included in the header.

Try this:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        with gzip.GzipFile('file.txt', 'wb', fileobj=f_out) as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making a distinction between 'stored file name' and 'archive name', but for gzip compression, this is the wrong way to think, because gzip is not an archive format, but just a compression protocol.

When you store a 'gzip' file, it does not (necessarily) remember the original filename. There is only the compressed contents of the original file, which you can give any name you want. There is a convention to give it the same name as the original file but with ".gz" appended. The "gzip" and "gunzip" utilities on Unix systems will assume this if you only supply a filename:

```
gzip foo.txt
# now foo.txt has been deleted, and foo.txt.gz exists
gunzip foo.txt.gz
# now you have foo.txt back, and foo.txt.gz has been deleted.
```

If you rename foo.txt.gz to bar.txt.gz, and then gunzip, you will get 'goo.txt' if you use Unix gunzip (but other utilities might do something different).

However, you can use gzip and gunzip in stream mode, in which case they know nothing about filenames - gzip is really about compression, and doesn't care about filenames.

(Edit: gzip can store a filename, but in some cases it can't (if there is no original "file", only data), and whether this is used or not when decompressing is entirely optional).

Comment: I think that's incorrect. The file name is most likely stored in the gzip file header mentioned on Wikipedia.

Try actually renaming a gzip file and then decompress it - you'll get back the file with the original name as previously. Or at least I'm getting it back with the software I have installed.

Comment: @brezniczky is correct with a modification, the "uncompressed name" is derived from the file name used with `gzip.open`. If you open the file `foo.txt.gz`, the uncompressed name in the header will be `foo.txt` even though the source file might be called `bar.txt`. See the [gzip module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L229) for the logic.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realise that gzip does actually store an original filename. Unix gunzip does not use this when decompressing unless you pass "-N", which is not the default, so it can't be relied on. Python modules might do something else, but in general, gzip should be considered a data compression format, not an archive format.